# Save user in my application db if i use keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am developing a simple e-commerce with spring boot, angular, and keycloak. I use keycloak to register the new user and in my application db I have the table Users. What can I do if I want to save the new users in this table?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the [Keycloak API Reference](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/rest-api/) ? Seems like there is a request to add a new user : "POST /{realm}/users"

Comment: Users is a table of an external db

Comment: What type of db is it ?

Comment: It is mysql database

Comment: Then you can just look up how to insert a row in mysql (and update your question to add the mysql tag), here's a quick example : https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_insert.asp

Comment: The problem is that I register the user form keycloak so I don't have the user information

Comment: Please edit your question to add an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you out (using stackblitz for instance)